# Bootstrap 3 navbar collapses and does not expand on Rails 5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked many times. I tried all suggested solutions but it still doesn't work for me.

FYI, instead of using the boostrap gem, I manually downloaded bootstrap distribution files (specifically bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js) and added them in my assets/stylesheets and assets/javascript directories respectively.

The problem is that when the page size is shrunk the navbar links get into a collapsed icon but nothing happens when I click the icon.

I see that this usually happens when javascript doesn't load, but I have included the necessary files in the application.js and also chrome's inspect tool doesn't show any errors or warnings (I suppose this is how you know if the javascript isn't getting loaded).

Here's the header partial with the navbar code:-

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-examplenavbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="navbar-brand">
            <%= link_to image_tag("sfund.svg", id:"nav-logo"), root_path %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-right nav-links">
            <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Application.html.erb:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>  

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
   .navbar {
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav li{
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align:center;
      background-color: #fff;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 1vw;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      margin-top: 10px;
      color: #000;
    }

    .nav-links li:hover {
      text-decoration-line: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: var(--shuddhiblue);
    }

    .navbar-brand {
      padding: 0;
    }
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require custom
 */
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: have u used `jquery-2.2.0.min` ?

Comment: My gemfile has this - gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1' and as you can see from the application.js file listed in the details, I have included = require jquery. Should I also include jquery-2.2.0.min separately from somewhere? Sorry, I'm not very experienced with this.

Comment: Sometime it happens for jQuery version that's why you can try `jquery-2.2.0.min`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can put `jquery-2.2.0.min` to `javascript` folder and then replace `//= require jquery-2.2.0.min` to `//= require jquery` in `application.js`

Comment: I just tried 2.2.0 and also tried the latest 3.2.1 but doesn't seem to work. I do think it's a javascript issue but can't seem to figure out where exactly the issue is.